# ch.qos.logback.classic and slf4j-log4j12

Tags: java, maven, slf4j, logback

I have an issue with logging of my application. Application uses slf4j and logback mechanism to implement logging.

Logger is initialised like

private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Classname.class);

But some how it was not able to generated the logs. During debugging I found error

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/xxx/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.5/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/xxx/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.0.13/logback-classic-1.0.13.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
```

then I tried removing the slf4j-log4j12 bindings from the parent pom.xml file which the application is grouped under. But still was not able to generate the logs.

Then I found the below entry in application iml file

```
<orderEntry type="library" scope="RUNTIME" name="Maven: org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.5" level="project" />
```

When I removed the entry my application was able to generate logs ... Currently I dont have any clue abt using which file as reference iml files are getting generated ? So Incase I need to exclude slf4j-log4j12 from getting built into my project should i remove it in pom.xml ?

Even if i remove it in pom.xml log does not get generated ?

Please let me know how should I resolve the issue of log not getting generated.

Comment: Is you logger configuration set up? Have you <exclude>ed the dependency to the logback library in your pom?

Comment: Logback configuration is setup and provided in file logback.xml .Also excluded in pom file <exclude>xxx/xxx/Logging.class</exclude>

Comment: You have to exclude the dependency using the gav coords from the dependency that uses the library. Not the class name.

Comment: I guess commons-logging is already added for commons-logging do I have to exclude anything else <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
        </exclusions>

Comment: The pronlem is, that you have to slf4j libs in your classpath. One is log4j, the other is logback. Remove one.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you are on the right track.  You need to use the the POM to exclude slf4j-log4j12 and commons-logging.

The iml file is generated by Intelli, you need to get intellij to reimport the pom to update the dependencies.  The best thing is to set intellij to always auto-reimport when the pom.xml changes.